# problem with live lubuntu application installation

Tags: software-installation, live-environment

When I install any applications in live OS mode and after shutdown all the applications were lost. Please someone help me to solve this problem so that I can save my applications in live OS mode even after shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot from a Live CD / DVD, the operating system is copied from the CD / DVD into a ramdisk, and every modification done to the currently running system is applied to the ramdisk. A ramdisk (per its scope) is going to lose all the informations contained in it upon shutdown (to be precise upon power cut; it also actually takes a while for the RAM capacitors to discharge, but that's another story). This means that any modification, pretty much like the type of memory in which gets stored, is volatile.

If you want to boot from a Live CD / DVD with some applications ready to be used, one solution is to [customize a Live CD / DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), altough this still won't allow you to store the applications' settings or any file.

If you want to store those, the only feasible solution is the installation of the operating system on a writable drive (such as on an internal hard disk or on a USB drive of any mean)